# How does Andromeda escape the black hole in S1E2

Tags: andromeda

In the second episode of Gene Roddenberry's Andromeda, "An Affirming Flame", the engines are down on the Andromeda, and their enemy/raider Gerentex pushes the ship towards a black hole. They decide to band together and shoot 40 sun-destroying bombs into the black hole, causing it to become a white hole (!) and push them away, before returning to normal and then sucking them back in. Fortunately, minutes later, when they need to escape, the engines work just fine.

*What did I miss? Were the able to jumpstart the engines by riding a shock wave? Do we just assume that the systems came back online in the few minutes they were blowing things up?*

[Here's a transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/Andromeda/102.htm), with parts quoted:

> ANDROMEDA [OC]: Engines are totally off-line. We're falling back into the singularity. I can't compensate.

...

> ROMMIE: Some of my peripheral systems are back online, but still no power to the engines.

...

Seemingly two or three minutes later, after they've nuked the singularity:

> BEKA: Hunt! Power up the engines. We've got to get out of here before it collapses back in on itself.

...

> ROMMIE: The white hole's becoming unstable. Normal gravitational
> fields are returning.
>
> BEKA: Come on. Here comes the riptide.
>
> HUNT: Just a few more seconds.
>
> ROMMIE: My engines are at fifteen percent
> over maximum.
>
> HUNT: We're almost far enough out to enter slipstream.
>
> ROMMIE: They're going to overload.
>
> HUNT: Slipstream now!

and then they escape.

I just can't tell what made the difference so that the engines would work.

Comment: I interpreted this to mean that whatever normal-space engines the Andromeda had were what was non-operational.   Slipstream drive is a separate system (demonstrated repeatedly through the course of the series).    Andromeda needed to be pushed far enough away that the Slipstream drive could be used.